# How to convert string-enum to enum in Reactjs typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have an enum like this in a `.ts` file:

```
export enum TimeOfDay{
    MORNING = "AM",
    NOON = "12noon",
    EVENING = "PM",
    MIDNIGHT = "12midnight"
}
```

In another `.tsx` file, I have a string `"12noon"` in a variable named `selectedOption` and I want to convert it into this enum. How can I do that?

I tried these based on the other answers in StackOverflow, but none of the worked:

```
var timeInDay: TimeOfDay = TimeOfDay[selectedOption];
```

The above is giving `TS7053` error.

```
var timeInDay: TimeOfDay = <TimeOfDay>selectedOption;
```

The above is giving `TS17008` and `TS2604` errors.

```
var timeInDay: TimeOfDay = (<any>TimeOfDay)[selectedOption];
```

The above is giving `TS2339` and `TS17008` errors.

I've gone through many answers on this site but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ways to use a `string` where a string enum type is expected:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAKglhYB5AZgEQIYE8DeBYAKCigFkkAlAOQElKBxKAXigCIBBElgGkOMqSSUmrAIwAmEAHtJIbrygBRAGoKa9YSwAKnHkVLU0NOgAkYG8RDgATEHADmACwAuLQgF9ChFGBABjJ3AyUFaSAMqSiE4OcCB2AOpwUfCIqJhYUAAUAYgAXLAIyOjYAJR5AG6S1lD4er4yAM6SADbAAHRNknZZBcUA3O6eBHUg9U5Q9cAt-sBWSAAOAUHMAOTiUjLL-QSEAPQ7UGz1UFiSYFCSAEYTAE5lM1xQUXBHIcD1IMtjAO6S1wDWOUIIXCkWisQSSQKqWwGQmUycM3mixAfV2+2IGMxWOxxAAfviCYTCWiDtc7JBQGNJChHlg5sAoMsWGtpLJllBnlApGMMPV6vYQBgLi1HpIoHMMNcMJFgNdzjSnHSGctkoU0stWoM9lAAKoTKAYcXXGZwXwYBGiqC+BzAXx-A1ja4+bLAQEEbx+ZEc+qq6HpDJlDBNMCu8ZOa4xOylKCB4MMzm+orpGrEY1OMDXEBQJAXABWtqcrVjIfqGUTaWKrRivmDVjeAaDIYNR3LJS2Hm2BDgNIyz1bWFhkwLiIWgRRxWq8mBEWAT3BiQc-cH8JHyL6UG1kj+A072qQ1we3eOp2WxqtsqcGBijwc5pvDNGEdi3oNMaDVUfkagoEgb7jum1KJQGPM4zSzMB9QwLNeRuZE3WnUFIwhRcoSTZdh1mUcgl5fIUiTddN23AggA)

```ts
enum TimeOfDay{
  MORNING = "AM",
  NOON = "12noon",
  EVENING = "PM",
  MIDNIGHT = "12midnight"
}

function doSomethingWithTimeOfDay (time: TimeOfDay): void {
  console.log(time);
}

const selectedOption = '12noon';

// As you observed, this doesn't work:
doSomethingWithTimeOfDay(selectedOption);
//                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"12noon"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TimeOfDay'.

// Use a predicate to check at runtime:
function isTimeOfDay (value: string): value is TimeOfDay {
  return Object.values(TimeOfDay).includes(value as TimeOfDay);
}

if (isTimeOfDay(selectedOption)) {
  doSomethingWithTimeOfDay(selectedOption); // ok
}

// Or, if you're certain that the string is a valid string enum value,
// then you can use an assertion:
doSomethingWithTimeOfDay(selectedOption as TimeOfDay); // ok
```

Comment: Isn't there a one-line code to convert string to enum?

Comment: @LightYagami Did you see the last line in my answer?

Comment: Is there a way to make the code print `NOON` instead of `12noon`?